# Copy only files that don't exist regardless of file name?

Tags: file-management, dropbox, deduplication

My dropbox account apparently renames all auto uploaded images. I'm about to clear my phone and I would like to verify that all images are in the dropbox folder before deleting them.
If they had their original file names it would have been a piece of cake, but now?

How can I only select/keep/copy only the missing files, if there are any?

Comment: Can you use an MD5 program on your phone? The hash it generates is unique per file and you could compare those values.

Comment: @Hennes The phone is an android, and I have it attached as a usb drive. Consider it a hard drive. I'm using windows 7 btw.

Comment: In that case: download a md5.exe on the windows computer and run something like this: `for %f in (*) do echo %f; md5.exe %f` to display the filename and that run md5 on it to calculate the hash.
Do something similar on the android phone (I am not familiar with android, though there seems to be a md5.jar when I google for *md5 for android*). Comparing both results you can match the dropbox names to the real names.